# Tailspin sample from wag.codeplex.com

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, azure

Can anyone shed any light on getting the TailSpin example project to execute. I've downloaded it from [wag.codeplex.com](http://wag.codeplex.com/), run the pre-req checker and gotten everything green, read the readme's and dropped the right libraries in the right places (I think)...anyway, to the extent that it builds with no errors. 1 warning and 33 Messages

It compiles, starts, global.aspx is executed and then nothing happens. Nothing is returned to the browser. I'm guessing this is because of the issues (below) in web.config - but what to do to fix it ?

*Warnings*

```
Warning 1 The 'type' attribute is not allowed. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 99 19 TailSpin.Web
```

*Messages*

```
Message 20 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'certificateValidationMode'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 71 30 TailSpin.Web
Message 18 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'findValue'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 69 77 TailSpin.Web
Message 10 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'issuer'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 65 54 TailSpin.Web
Message 34 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 88 70 TailSpin.Web
Message 25 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'optional'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 75 88 TailSpin.Web
Message 28 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'optional'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 76 90 TailSpin.Web
Message 9 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'passiveRedirectEnabled'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 65 23 TailSpin.Web
Message 11 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'realm'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 65 107 TailSpin.Web
Message 12 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'requireHttps'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 65 137 TailSpin.Web
Message 14 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'requireSsl'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 66 24 TailSpin.Web
Message 33 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'thumbprint'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 88 16 TailSpin.Web
Message 24 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'type'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 75 22 TailSpin.Web
Message 27 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'type'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 76 22 TailSpin.Web
Message 30 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'type'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 86 27 TailSpin.Web
Message 6 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'value'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 62 14 TailSpin.Web
Message 17 Could not find schema information for the attribute 'x509FindType'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 69 31 TailSpin.Web
Message 5 Could not find schema information for the element 'add'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 62 10 TailSpin.Web
Message 32 Could not find schema information for the element 'add'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 88 12 TailSpin.Web
Message 21 Could not find schema information for the element 'applicationService'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 72 8 TailSpin.Web
Message 4 Could not find schema information for the element 'audienceUris'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 61 8 TailSpin.Web
Message 16 Could not find schema information for the element 'certificateReference'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 69 10 TailSpin.Web
Message 19 Could not find schema information for the element 'certificateValidation'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 71 8 TailSpin.Web
Message 23 Could not find schema information for the element 'claimType'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 75 12 TailSpin.Web
Message 26 Could not find schema information for the element 'claimType'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 76 12 TailSpin.Web
Message 22 Could not find schema information for the element 'claimTypeRequired'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 73 10 TailSpin.Web
Message 13 Could not find schema information for the element 'cookieHandler'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 66 10 TailSpin.Web
Message 7 Could not find schema information for the element 'federatedAuthentication'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 64 8 TailSpin.Web
Message 29 Could not find schema information for the element 'issuerNameRegistry'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 86 8 TailSpin.Web
Message 2 Could not find schema information for the element 'microsoft.identityModel'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 59 4 TailSpin.Web
Message 3 Could not find schema information for the element 'service'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 60 6 TailSpin.Web
Message 15 Could not find schema information for the element 'serviceCertificate'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 68 8 TailSpin.Web
Message 31 Could not find schema information for the element 'trustedIssuers'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 87 10 TailSpin.Web
Message 8 Could not find schema information for the element 'wsFederation'. C:\Users\Andrew Hawken\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WAG-Code-RC\SourceCode\TailSpin\TailSpin.Web\Web.config 65 10 TailSpin.Web
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After feedback from the owners at wag.codeplex.com it seems that the source on codeplex is out of date. You need to get it from [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966499.aspx) However its not tested with the current version of Azure.